# Replace HTML button with text/code when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button

I would like to have a button that disappears when clicked on and replaced with something else. The code below causes the words "Some text" to appear below the button when it's clicked on. That's not quite what I want though -- how do I get "Some text" to appear *in place of* the button?

```
<button id="MyButton">Click</button>

<script>
    function addListener() {
        document.getElementById("MyButton").addEventListener("click", ReplaceButton, false)
    }

    addListener()

    function ReplaceButton() {
        node = document.getElementById("MyButton")
        node.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<p>Some text</p>") 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. inside the click listener, you can use `this` to get the button 2. simply use `node.remove()`

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `this.outerHTML` also works and keeps it simple:

```html
<button onclick="this.outerHTML='<p>some text</p>'">Click</button>
```

Comment: I also like potatoes 

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```js
<button id="MyButton">Click</button>
<script>
   document.getElementById("MyButton").addEventListener(
      "click",
      ({ target: button }) => {
        button.insertAdjacentText("afterend", "Some text");
        button.remove();
      },
      false
   );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ReplaceButton() {
    // Get the button
    node = document.getElementById("MyButton");
    // Add some HTML after the button (in the buttons parent)
    node.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<p>Some text</p>");
    // Hide the button, optionally remove from tree with `node.remove()`
    node.style.display = "none";
}
```